# Отчет времени в C#

Tags: c#

У меня 2 вопроса. 
  1. Вот скажите, я хочу сделать программу, где в statusbar'e будет отображаться сколько  осталось до 18 ноября. Т.е примерно так :

```
  До дня рождения осталось : 18 дней 12:10:5
```

Какой код будет примерно использоваться? Только не просто дата, а дата + время.

> 12 - часы 10 - минуты 5 - секунды.

1. Как можно сделать так, чтобы музыка сама начала играть при запуске программы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сейчас не нет компилятора под рукой, не могу проверить,но примерно так:

```
    DateTime finishDate = new DateTime(2011, 11, 18, 12, 0, 0);
    TimeSpan left = finishDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
    double daysLeft = left.TotalDays;
    Console.WriteLine("**До дня рождения осталось : " + daysLeft.ToString("0"));
```

А можно еще проще:

```
Console.WriteLine("**До дня рождения осталось : {0:dd\\.hh\\:mm\\:ss}", left);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все получилось.

Comment: Ээээ дни то получились, а вот часы, минуты,секунды не отображаются((

Comment: А если подумать!?

left.TotalHours;
left.TotalMinutes;
left.TotalSeconds;
left.TotalMilliseconds;